# Finding $\iiint_R e^{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3}} dA$ with spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

How to integrate the following expression

$$\iiint_R e^{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3}} dA\,,$$

where $R$ is a sphere with radius $1$ centered in the origin?

I did

$$\iiint_R e^{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3}} dA = 4\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 e^{\sqrt{\rho^3}} \rho^2 \sin{\phi} \,d\rho \,d \phi \,d \theta$$

But my question is if it's correct to consider the first octant, as I did, and then just multiplying it by $4$ since the exponential function relies on positive $z$-axis.

Comment: Is $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+x^2)^3}$ correct exponent?

Comment: My bad, I edited it. Thanks for the remark

Comment: It's a bit weird to use $dA$ for volume - but be that as it may... Reconsider how many "octants" there are - are there 4? Next, $\rho =( x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{1/2}$. So reconsider your expression for the exponent on the $e$.

Comment: To @FunnyNianCat: Now check the exponent $\sqrt{\rho^3}$, i.e. see the comment given by **peter a g**.

Comment: Thanks, the exponent comes from $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \sqrt{r^2+z^2} = \rho \sqrt{\sin^2+\cos^2} $. Then, regarding the region of integration, should I take the whole space. That is, multiplying by $8$?

Comment: To @FunnyNianCat: In spherical coordinates we have $x^2+y^2+z^2 = \rho^2$...

Answer (score 1):

The exponent is actually $\sqrt{(\rho^2)^3}=\rho^3$, i.e. your last $\sqrt{}$ operator is unneeded. Then$$\int_0^1\rho^2e^{\rho^3}d\rho=[e^{\rho^3}/3]_0^1=(e-1)/3.$$The rest of the integral is just a factor of the sphere's surface, $4\pi$.

The variable $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is more normally denoted $r$, though, with $\rho$ preserved for a cylindrical coordinate $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: By factor of the sphere's surface, do you mean just the upper part? So it's correct to say that $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ and then multiplying it by $4$?

Comment: @FunnyNianCat Your question as stated was for the entire sphere $0\le\phi\le2\pi, \, 0\le\theta\le\pi$ (if you don't understand why these ranges have unequal lengths, I suggested studying solid angles in more detail). This means we get $8$ orthants, not $4$.